# MS Access equivalent to Application.International(xlListSeparator)?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I found the following code at http://analystcave.com/excel-calculate-distances-between-addresses/#Calculate_distance_between_two_addresses_using_Google_Maps_in_Excel

But want to use it in my Access DB to take the values from 2 text boxes on a form and then calculate the distance and return the distance in meters into a third textbox on the form when a command button is clicked. When I use the code, it throws up an error for the part of the code that uses the fn Application.International(xlListSeparator). How can I get this to work in Access?

```
'Calculate Google Maps distance between two addresses
Public Function GetDistance(start As String, dest As String)
    Dim firstVal As String, secondVal As String, lastVal As String
    firstVal = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="
    secondVal = "&destinations="
    lastVal = "&mode=car&language=pl&sensor=false"
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = firstVal & Replace(start, " ", "+") & secondVal & Replace(dest, " ", "+") & lastVal
    objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send ("")
    If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, """distance"" : {") = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandl
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"): regex.Pattern = """value"".*?([0-9]+)": regex.Global = False
    Set matches = regex.Execute(objHTTP.responseText)
    tmpVal = Replace(matches(0).SubMatches(0), ".", Application.International(xlListSeparator))
    GetDistance = CDbl(tmpVal)
    Exit Function
ErrorHandl:
    GetDistance = -1
End Function
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38724667/4088852). Just change the locale (unless you need it in Polish).

Comment: ...and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36706171/4088852) is the method to get the system list separator via the Windows API.

Comment: Why in the world do you replace a dot with a list separator before calling CDbl on the value?

Comment: @Comintern: Thanks :)

Comment: What is the error the code throws up? A very important tidbit to include.

Comment: It just bring back the delimiter for a local list.  Just change `Application.International(xlListSeparator)` to a separator of your choice. e.g. `","`

Answer (score 0):

If you ignore `Application.International(xlListSeparator)` bit and just use:

```
tmpVal = matches (0).SubMatches (0)
```

It does the trick for me in MS Access.